# MongoDB References how to?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collections in MongoDB (I also use node js)

```
First:
{ _id: "France", color: "red", Refid: { "1": "FRA1", "2": "FRA2"}}

Second:

{ _id: "FRA1", color: "blue", info : "Country"}
{ _id: "FRA2", color: "white", info : "Country"}
```

How can I display data in for example console.log to show me the reference beetwen collections?
I would like the data to be displayed in this way(when I  type db.first.find().pretty()):

```
    { _id: "France", color: "red", Refid: 
{ "1": "FRA1", color: "blue", info : "Country", 
"2": "FRA2", color: "white", info : "Country"}
}
}
```

Comment: There are no joins on mongodb. That means you either embed the information on the first collection or join the results on the client side.

Comment: Could some tell me how does the query look like to display data in they way I want?